# Composite index with a range column in the middle

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning, myisam

My understanding is that when designing a composite index a column, which will be used for range tests should be placed at the end of this index, because the usage of the columns in composite indexes stops after the first range column.

The things is that `EXPLAIN` shows that also a column after a range column in used by optimizer. That is why I am confused and not sure how to properly design my composite indexes.

Below is a simplified example of my table. For each date `DateP` there is a number of objects `Object`. Each `Object` has 3 underlying sub-objects `subObject`. `subObject` is a unique name for each `DateP` and it is derived from `Object` by adding a number. `subObject` has an integer identifier `subObjectId`, which is usually 0, 1 or 2 and it is unique within the same `Object`.

| subObject | Object | DateP | subObjectId | counter1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa1 | aaa | 2019-06-01 | 0 | 10 |
| aaa2 | aaa | 2019-06-01 | 1 | 13 |
| aaa3 | aaa | 2019-06-01 | 2 | 11 |
| bbb1 | bbb | 2019-06-01 | 0 | 9 |
| bbb2 | bbb | 2019-06-01 | 1 | 6 |
| bbb3 | bbb | 2019-06-01 | 2 | 7 |
| aaa1 | aaa | 2019-06-02 | 0 | 14 |
| aaa2 | aaa | 2019-06-02 | 1 | 12 |
| aaa3 | aaa | 2019-06-02 | 2 | 16 |

`CREATE TABLE` code is below. Table engine is MyISAM and server is MySQL 8.

```
CREATE TABLE `testTab` (
  `DateP` date NOT NULL,
  `Object` char(6) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `subObject` char(11) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `subObjectId` int NOT NULL,
  `counter1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  ......
  PRIMARY KEY (`subObject`,`DateP`,`subObjectId`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Object` (`Object`,`DateP`,`subObjectId`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

The most unique column from the `KEY` is `Object`, followed by `DateP`. The least unique is `subObjectId`. As far as I know the uniqueness of the columns also matters for their order in a composite index - the most unique should be leftmost.

Following you can see different versions of `EXPLAIN` depending on the conditions in `WHERE` clause.

1. All three columns from the composite index are presented. In the middle is the range test of `DateP`. Nevertheless `subObjectId` column in also used by Optimizer after the range test. `key_len` is **31**.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DateP,Object,SUM(counter1)
FROM testTab
WHERE Object='aaa' AND DateP>='2019-06-01' AND DateP<='2019-06-10' AND (subObjectId=0 OR subObjectId=1)
GROUP BY Object,DateP
```

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | testTab | NULL       | range | Object        | Object | 31      | NULL |   28 |    19.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

2. The first and second columns are presented in `WHERE` clause, so it finishes with the range test. `key_len` is **27**.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DateP,Object,SUM(counter1)
FROM testTab
WHERE Object='aaa' AND DateP>='2019-06-01' AND DateP<='2019-06-10'
GROUP BY Object,DateP
```

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | testTab | NULL       | range | Object        | Object | 27      | NULL |   29 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

3. Only the first column is used in `WHERE`. `key_len` is **24**.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DateP,Object,SUM(counter1)
FROM testTab
WHERE Object='aaa' 
GROUP BY Object,DateP
```

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | testTab | NULL       | ref  | Object        | Object | 24      | const |  417 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

My conclusion is that all three columns from the composite index can be used despite that in the middle is a column for range tests. But can I expect that the optimizer will always respect the third column?

In my current design `KEY` is designed with `DateP` column at the end.

```
KEY `Object` (`Object`,`subObjectId`,`DateP`) USING BTREE
```

But this order is not suitable for `GROUP BY` clause, which is:

```
GROUP BY Object,DateP
```

In this case for grouping I guess only `Object` column is used, because I skip the middle column `DateP`. Query execution ends with `Using temporary`.

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | testTab | NULL       | range | Object        | Object | 31      | NULL |   20 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: "Using index condition" means the next: the server uses the index not like sorted columns set but only like compact version of the table. I.e. it uses index scanning, not index seeking. Depends on the columns order the server may use an index prefix for pre-seeking (and grouping) with subsequent scanning, or it can use complete index scanning (and temprowset for grouping). Looking at the query I'd recommend you to include `counter1` column into the index expression, this will the index to be covering one, and hence this will improve.

Comment: @Akina unfortunately I cannot include ```counter1```, because it is just one column out of many. For simplicity in the example I dropped the rest columns.

Comment: I see... I mention the improvement provided by the covering index in theory. See https://dbfiddle.uk/c-g50AXl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random notes:

- "composite index used for range tests should [have the range column] at the end of this index -- true; that's 'should', not 'must'
- "the most unique [column] should be leftmost [in an index]" -- myth
- `CHAR` should be used only for fixed length strings.
- MyISAM should be abandoned for InnoDB.
- "But can I expect that the optimizer will always respect the third column?" -- Try `WHERE Object='aaa' AND subObjectId=1` (without testing/grouping `DateP`).

Let's discuss further my first bullet item.

- For an index to be efficiently used, the `WHERE` needs to walk through it, using each item it finds. Skipping over rows makes it less efficient.
- When *all* columns that show up *anywhere* in the `SELECT` are found *anywhere* in *one* `INDEX`, that index is called "covering".  (None of your three examples show that -- because of needing `counter1`.)  A covering index has the extra advantage of not needing to bounce between the index and te data repeated to find more columns.
- So, the optimal index is both covering and ordered as follows:

1. all columns tested via just `=` (or `IS NULL`) first.
2. the best non-`=` test next.
3. other columns to make it "covering".  (This runs into problems if you need lots of columns or big columns.)

More notes:

- `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY` may tug at the ordering -- to avoid a sort.  Note that all 3 of your examples can avoid sorting because the index starts with `Object, DateP` in the desired order.
- A single `INDEX(Object, DateP, subObjectid, counter)` would be optimal for the first query and semi-optimal for the other two.

More:  [*Index Cookbook*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: As usual you provide very useful advices :) I altered the index of my big table, so that to place the range column ```DateP``` in the middle. All the tests that I performed showed that no matter that the range scan column is in second position in the composite index, also the third member ```subObjectid``` is used by the optimizer. I don't know how it come that on many places I read that the usage of composite index is stopped after the first range column. Apparently this is not true.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` does not give the complete story, especially on whether or not the columns after a "range" are useful.  "Covering" is indicated by "Using index"; "Using index condition" is less useful (and may not be useful for MyISAM).

Comment: After changing the index from ```INDEX(Object, subObjectid, DateP )``` to ```INDEX(Object, DateP, subObjectid)``` I removed some of the actions in ```Extra``` column of ```EXPLAIN```. It used to be ```Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort```, now it is ```Using index condition```. Apparently ```GROUP BY``` AND ```ORDER BY``` were optimized. Also ```key_len``` shows that all columns in index are used - I hope ```EXPLAIN``` is not misleading me as you suggest that could happen. I can't create covering index, because I have quite many columns in table.

Comment: `Using index` implies "covering".